# Error ocurred while trying to compile

Tags: c

Two errors appear when I try to compile this:

```
typedef struct {

int account_number;
float balance;


}accounts[2];


typedef struct{
char name[40];
accounts[2]


}client[3];
```

The errors are :

```
prac5_2.c:16:8: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token 
accounts[2]

prac5_2.c:18:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘client’
}client[3];
```

And I don´t know what I have to write for it to be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `accounts[2]` in the second `typedef` is causing the error.

Modify the code to match the specfication. For example, you can delete the line or add a variable name and a semicolon to the line in order to get lid of the error.

```
typedef struct{
    char name[40];
    /* accounts[2] */
    accounts hoge[2];
}client[3];
```

Note that your code declares `accounts` as a type which is 2-element array of the struct having `account_number` and `balance`. `accounts hoge[2];` will be 2x2 array of the struct. Like that, `client` will be a type which is 3-element array.

---

If you want to just create types that are structs, not arrays of structs, you can write like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int account_number;
    float balance;
}accounts_t;
accounts_t accounts[2];


typedef struct{
    char name[40];
    accounts_t accounts[2];
}client_t;
client_t client[3];
```

Note that in this code, `accounts` in the strucct `client_t` is 1-dimention array of 2 elements, not 2x2 array.

Comment: @ManuelGonzález [Corrected code will work](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/R1CHr8038cJ8T9Fa). What error do you get?

Comment: After doing what you said this error appears:                                   prac5_2.c: In function ‘main’:
prac5_2.c:24:14: error: expected expression before ‘client’
  scanf("%s", client[0].name);

Comment: @ManuelGonzález As I said, `client` is not a variable but a type name. Declare variables having the type and use it instead.

Comment: So In the main void instead of typing client I should type hoge right?